# how to make auto-capitalize-mode downcase next word upon auto-capitalization?

Tags: capitalization

Suppose I have a sentence:

```
Two three four.
```

Suppose I put the point on the "T" in "Two" and enter the text `one`<kbd>SPC</kbd>. Auto-capitalize-mode will recognize that the point is at the beginning of a line or sentence, and will automatically capitalize the "O" in "One."

Current output:

```
One Two three four.
```

But since "Two" is no longer the beginning of the sentence, can I get auto-capitalize-mode to automatically downcase the next word in the sentence if there is one?

Desired output:

```
One two three four.
```

In other words, how can I instruct auto-capitalize-mode to downcase the next word whenever it auto-capitalizes a word if there is another word after the point before a line break or period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, building on @glucas's idea to use `defadvice`. This code works, but I'm just starting to learn Lisp (and programming) so feel free to suggest improvements to my code.

```
(defadvice capitalize-word (after capitalize-word-advice activate)
"After capitalizing the new first word in a sentence, downcase the next word, since that next word is no longer the first word in the sentence." 
(unless 
  (or
   (looking-at " I\\b") ; never downcase the word "I" 
   (looking-at (sentence-end))
   (looking-at "[ ]*$") ; hopefully this means "zero or more whitespaces, then end of line"
   (looking-at (user-full-name))
   )
 (downcase-word 1)))
```

I also created a companion function to re-capitalize the first word of the next already existing sentence if you wind up typing an entire sentence with a period at the end:

```
(defun smart-period ()
"When you type a period, capitalize the first word of the next sentence."
(interactive)
(insert ".") 
(save-excursion
(unless (looking-at "[ ]*$") ; zero or more whitespaces, then line break
(capitalize-unless-org-heading))
))
```

And since I didn't know how to concatenate looking-at regexps, I created an exception for org-mode headings in a separate function:

```
(defun capitalize-unless-org-heading ()
(interactive)
(unless (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp)
(capitalize-word 1)
))
```

Answer (score 2):

In your specific example you can hit `M-l` to down-case the next word.

A general solution would involve some code: you'd want a custom function to run after `auto-capitalize` and call `downcase-word`. You also want to make sure the next word is part of the same sentence first. Something like:

```
(defun downcase-next-word-in-sentence ()
  (interactive)
  "Downcase the next word after point, unless at the end of a sentence or line."
  (unless (looking-at (sentence-end)) 
    (downcase-word 1)))
```

You can probably advise `auto-capitalize` to call this after it executes.

**Update**

Using 'after' advice does not seem to work here. In fact, once I add any advice to `auto-capitalize` it seems to stop working altogether. Not sure why that is -- perhaps someone else can comment.

The other limitation with this approach is that it is blindly downcasing the next word. After looking at the source of auto-capitalize I see it is doing smarter things like checking for words that are always supposed to be capitalized ("I"), etc.

Comment: Agreed that it's not ideal to blindly downcase the next word. At the very least it would be great to have an exception for the word "I." A more intelligent function could also make exceptions for any capitalized proper nouns listed in flyspell global dictionaries ("Paris") and user local dictionaries ("Daenerys"), but that would be way more complicated. So just an exception for "I" is probably the place to start.

Comment: Not sure if any code from this would help. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10632/search-for-and-correct-capitalized-words-that-are-not-at-the-beginning-of-a-sent?rq=1 Obviously I don't want to globally search and replace trying to find sentences like they are doing. As you correctly noted, I want a function that will run only as an after advice to auto-capitalize.

Comment: what about this? `(defadvice capitalize-word (after capitalize-word-advice activate)
  (unless 
(or
(looking-at " I")
(looking-at (sentence-end)))
    (downcase-word 1)))
`

Comment: Not quite: this will ignore any words starting with "I". You probably want something like `(looking-at " I\\b")` to only match I followed by a word boundary. Is this working for you with `auto-capitalize`? I don't have that installed anymore.

Comment: Here's my inept, non-programmer's attempt at an entire advice. Doesn't work as intended at the moment. `(defadvice capitalize-word (after capitalize-word-advice activate)
"
  (unless 
(or
(looking-at " I\\b")
(looking-at (sentence-end))
(looking at (line-end)); doesn't work 
(looking-at (user-full-name))
)
    (downcase-word 1)))
`

Comment: Better formatting here: http://pastebin.com/s9WsmBcH

Comment: Perhaps a better approach than hard coding a list of capitalized words would be to build your `looking-at` regex from the same `auto-capitalize-words` list that auto-capitalize uses. When I get a chance I'll update my answer based on your findings so far and this suggestion. Also: I'm curious about your handling of line endings -- shouldn't a line break be irrelevant in deciding what to up/downcase?

Comment: Awesome, looking forward! To your question about line breaks, yes, it's necessary. Here's an example. http://pastebin.com/4MrhAaNY Suppose the point is where the carat is and you type "four five six. " Current behavior will downcase the next org-mode heading—unwanted behavior.

Comment: do you know how to make the downcase-word call stop when it finds a line break?

Comment: I suspect it's not really about line breaks? In text mode a sentence continuing on the next line should still be treated normally. You might want to handle org separately - there are org commands to navigate by element that might be used to check if you're at the end of a headline.

Comment: that sounds more complicated than it needs to be. I only use org anyway, and a line break covers all cases, including numbered lists, bulleted lists, new headings, new TODO headings, block quotes, source code blocks, literal examples, etc without the need to parse different elements.